# Admin page couldn't get found

Tags: python, django

Here come my urls.py page code:

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path 

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I run Django I get **404** error:

> Page not found (404) Request
>   Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:51169/admin Using the
>   URLconf defined in DjangoWebProject3.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ The current path, admin, didn't match any of these.

I know this is a famous problem but couldn't find any answer for it.

What is wrong?

Comment: have you created any app?

Comment: Please post the full error code

Comment: You get a 404 error where? What page are you going to?

Comment: Note you don't need the `admin.autodiscover()` line in Django 1.7+.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I've added

Answer (score 1):

The admin url is `http://localhost:51169/admin/`. You are missing the trailing slash.

Normally, Django should redirect from `/admin` to `/admin/`. If it hasn't it suggests that you've changed something in the settings, or you've upgraded Django from an older version without switching from `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to `MIDDLEWARE` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: I add the trailing slash but then I faced this error: AttributeError at /admin/
AttributeError at /admin/

Comment: As I said, it sounds like you've upgraded Django without updating your settings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327642/attributeerror-at-admin-by-django-wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user).

Comment: you are right, now it works and I can see the admin page!!

Answer (score 0):

As Alasdair commented I  updated my Django but didn't update my settings before:
Know:
In the setting, I changed middleware_classes to middleware and commented one of the middlewares: #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'

now login page works!!

thank you,